# How to represent the admin in this case?

Tags: uml, use-case

[image]

The admin is able to do everything the same as the user, AND see and modify the tickets that are not theirs. Normal users can only do all that on the tickets that they have created. Another difference is that the admin gets a list of all the tickets, while users get a list of their own tickets only (the "Show all tickets" extension). Those are the only differences between the user and the admin.

How do I represent the admin?
Adding another actor and connecting to all doesn't seem like a good idea.

Each of the ticket related use cases have a condition "User created the ticket.", simply adding "OR user is an admin" would pretty much do the job, but then it wouldn't be clear that the system has an admin. The problem is that the admin is basically a user with one additional permission.

Comment: Basically look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232352/use-case-diagram-how-do-it-better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it isn't directly explained in UML specification, you can add another user admin, show generalization between actors where admin is a specialization of user and link UCs that can be performed by admin only to admin actor while UCs available to user (and admin) only to user actor.

A specialized actor has access (can run) all UCs of an actor it specializes plus its own UCs.

Such approach is suggested e.g. by Howard Podesva (see "UML for IT Business Analysts") and is compliant with UML specification.

Note also that the association between actor and Use Case shows only that the actor is somehow involved in UC. While in most cases it is initiation it doesn't have to be always the case.

Comment: One can introduce a nomenclature to differentiate between primary and secondary actor. E.g. I used a directed assoc. for the primary and an undirected use relation for the secondary. There are also people who say that there should only be a primary actor for a UC.

Comment: @ThomasKilian as for putting only primary actors UML specification is clear and whichever actor interacts with the UC, they should be associated to it (however one should also remember that UML provides a model and a model might ignore some information - like secondary actor). I follow the same rule for noting primary/secondary actor and it is also used e.g. on official OMG UML exams.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Now both admin and user can do the same thing, but admin can have few extra use cases.

Comment: That's how I've done it. Ister was a bit faster and gave a better explanation so I chose his answer. I've upvoted yours.